# Summarizing SQL table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a SQL table that looks something like this:

[image]

Table definition:

CREATE TABLE TestSessions (Id INTEGER IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY not null, TestUser varchar(50) not null, Department varchar(50) not null, Project varchar(50) not null, TestDateTime varchar(50) not null, Score varchar(50) not null, Pass varchar(50) not null);

I would like to group the table by TestUser and count each Pass (Passes and Fails separately) value for each TestUser so that it should look like:

[image]

SQL command: "SELECT TestUser, SUM(CASE WHEN [Score] = 'Pass' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)[Pass], SUM( CASE WHEN[Score] = 'Fail' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)[Fail] FROM TestSessions GROUP BY TestUser"

Returns:

[image]

How can I fix this?

Then I would like to calculate rate between Passes and Fails.

Is that possible in one statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, your CASE should check on the column [Pass] instead of [Score], since [Score] never contains "Pass" or "Fail. Secondly, you could try and write a cte around it, like the following:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT TestUser
        ,Department
        ,CASE WHEN [Pass] = 'Pass' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END [Passed]
        ,CASE WHEN[Pass] = 'Fail' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END [Failed]
  FROM TestSessions
)
SELECT TestUser
      ,Department
      ,sum([Passed]) [Pass]
      ,sum([Failed]) [Fail]
  FROM cte
  GROUP BY TestUser, Department
```

Answer (score 5):

You need a simple aggregation and a `CASE` expression:

```
SELECT  Color,
        SUM(CASE WHEN [BOOL] = 'TRUE' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) [True],
        SUM(CASE WHEN [BOOL] = 'FALSE' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) [False]
FROM dbo.YourTable
GROUP BY Color;
```

This assumes that the datatype of `BOOL` is a varchar, if it's a bit, then you need to do:

```
SELECT  Color,
        SUM(CASE WHEN [BOOL] = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) [True],
        SUM(CASE WHEN [BOOL] = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) [False]
FROM dbo.YourTable
GROUP BY Color;
```

Comment: All I get in return are zeroes. There should be sums. Please, treat true and false like strings (varchar).

Comment: @LadislavBiskupec As I said in my answer, this depends on the datatype of the `BOOL` column. The first code treats them as `varchar`, the second as `bit`

Comment: @LadislavBiskupec you can test the conditional part (`case`) by itself by doing `SELECT  *, CASE WHEN [BOOL] = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as MyTest FROM dbo.YourTable`.  When you have that returning a 0 or 1 like  you need, paste it into the original query (with `SUM`, etc)

Comment: @Lamak And I did use the simple aggregation and a CASE expression if it vas varchar. The result is a table with zeroes. No sums.

Comment: @LadislavBiskupec then please post some sample data and the exact query, because it sounds that those are not `varchar`  values. Also please post the table definition

Comment: @Lamak Bool (True and False) are varchar values. The result (count True and count False) should be Int value. To not confuse you any further, replace True and False with "A" and "B" and see if you can do the aggregation. Thank You for Your efforts Lamak! I really appreciate this.

Comment: but what I'm saying is that this should already work if they are actually varchar. So, please, post the table definition

Comment: @Lamak CREATE TABLE TestSessions (Id INTEGER IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY not null, TestUser varchar(50) not null, Department varchar(50) not null, Project varchar(50) not null, TestDateTime varchar(50) not null, Score varchar(50) not null, Pass varchar(50) not null); Score is the True/False and it is actually Pass/Fail. I want to count Passes and Fails.

Comment: @LadislavBiskupec well, then replace the ``True'` and `'False'` with `'Pass'` and `'Fail'`

Comment: Try to put a cte around it (WITH cte AS (SELECT TestUser, CASE...END AS Pass, ...). And basing on this query the sums as mentioned in your example. As far as I remember SQL Server behaves a bit bitchy if it comes to calculating on case results.

Comment: @Tyron78 "WITH cte AS (SELECT TestUser, Department, SUM(CASE WHEN [Score] = 'Pass' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)[Pass], SUM( CASE WHEN[Score] = 'Fail' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)[Fail] FROM TestSessions GROUP BY TestUser, Department) SELECT * FROM cte " - Still zeroes :(

Comment: Sorry, I meant the case within the cte and the sum soutside... like the following: "WITH cte AS (
  SELECT TestUser, Department, CASE WHEN [Pass] = 'Pass' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END[Passed], CASE WHEN[Pass] = 'Fail' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END[Failed]
    FROM TestSessions
)
SELECT TestUser, Department, sum([Passed]) [Pass], sum([Failed]) [Fail]
  FROM cte
  GROUP BY TestUser, Department"

Comment: @Tyron78 Still zeroes. Maybe I should do this trough c# with DataTable.

Comment: Did you copy my full query? I changed the column in your case; you checked on the column "score" but you should check on the column "pass", since there is NEVER a SCORE with "pass" or "fail"

Comment: I added it as answer - would be great if you could accempt it! Thanks.